Index organized table (IOT) vs composite index
I got a table that looks like this
Create table CROSSWALK
(
OtherTable_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
OtherTableName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
MyTable_ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
MyTableTYPE VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (OtherTable_ID, OtherTableName,MyTable_ID,MyTableTYPE
)

Its a many to many relationship. I am mostly going to be using it to find tables and rows in my db when I provide it a OtherTableName and OtherTable_ID from the other database.
Should I use and IOT (organization index) or just do a composite index on OtherDB_ID and OtherDBType?
The reason I ask is I will never actually be searching by the full composite primary key. I will be searching by id and type fields of "Other", or "My" individually

An IOT is very efficient when you search by the full primary key, typically using equalities. If you are going to search by other combinations of columns, please include the specific queries you want to optimize, to provide a good answer.

All columns in your table are indexed, thus an index organized table is a valid option. I think a normal table with composite index will work as well, however it will use double disc space. When you run queries, then Oracle will always read only the index but never the table, i.e. a normal table is just a waste of space.

@TheImpaler I would be doing a select from CrossWalk where OtherTable_ID=2 and OtherTableName = User
This is just an example.

I probably would not use an IOT in this situation, though it probably doesn't make a huge difference. Whether or not to use an IOT is more complex than most folks realize.
An IOT makes sense when (1) you intend to use index-access almost exclusively, (2) you have only one column or stable set of columns that your queries will use in their access predicates. Hence, there is no need for a second index beyond the PK. Further, (3) you typically want to retrieve most of the columns in the table, or a significant number of columns, and (4) you either cannot use heap compression or HCC compression or have no desire to.
Let me go through these one-by-one:

An IOT is an index with additional non-ordered columns (those not in the PK) stored inside the index leaf blocks. If the primary access method will be a full scan (analytic/report-style query), the linked-list nature of index blocks would require a lot of single block I/O which is much less efficient than multiblock reads for scanning an entire segment. Oracle can opt for a "fast full scan" of an index which overcomes this and can even be parallel and direct path, but you're still paying an index-maintenance premium on insert for sorting and reusing existing blocks (possibly splitting them and relinking) that is amplified by the wider index entries than you'd have on a normal heap table with a narrower b-tree index on top of it. Wider entries = fewer rows per block = more blocks to format, split and relink.

If you have more than one way to get at the data, you'll need more than one index. Even if you don't, the likely FK constraints you'll probably want on a bridge table like this will push you to index both IDs separately anyway. Only one of those indexes can be the primary key and thus structure the IOT. The other index is the problem: non-PK indexes on an IOT cannot store ROWIDs; they can only store the PK column values in place of a ROWID. This makes these indexes very wide and space-inefficient, as you are having to implicitly repeat the PK columns in every single non-PK index. And when you query such an index, while Oracle does have some optimizations to mitigate the impact, in many cases you'll have to binary search both the initial index and the PK. So non-PK index access on an IOT is less efficient than normal indexing on a heap table. In your example, both OtherTable_ID and MyTable_ID are likely to be indexed, so this would argue against using an IOT for this situation.

If you want only one or two small columns outside the PK, adding those columns to the end of a normal index on a heap table is more efficient than an IOT, as you only have to hit the index and it's relatively narrow (hence more compact and hence less blocks to read). In an IOT, all the columns are stored in the index, so it is far less compact and requires more block reads. If however you want all or most of the non-PK columns in your result, that's a possible fit for an IOT.

An IOT cannot be heap or HCC compressed. The only compression available is index prefix compression, which suppresses repetition of repeated column values by creating prefix groups in the block and then storing a pointer to the prefix group in each index entry. Typically however this achieves much lower compression efficiency (10%-30% reduction is common) than the various forms of heap compression. And, unless you are using the paid ACO option, it has to be manually defined for each index which requires careful analysis of the cardinalities of your PK columns or use of the old analyze index command to let Oracle compute the optimal prefix setting for you. So if you have a lot of columns outside the PK and need some decent compression to reduce space consumption, you're best off with a traditional heap segment and limit your index segments to only the necessary index-candidate columns. With a bridge table, however, this is rarely a major concern.


If it were me and I had your bridge table, I would (a) remove the denormalized columns (OtherTableName,MyTableTYPE - those should be elsewhere, in the tables where each of the bridge table IDs are the PK), (b) create a heap table with a PK across both key columns using one order, and (c) create another index across both columns using the reverse order. This permits index-only access either way you access it, which for bridge tables is often desirable. Both indexes can use a prefix compression level of 1 to save a little space without any penalty. The table itself can be heap compressed if needed but it's unusual for a bridge table to employ compression so likely won't.
The downside to this approach is you'd be storing the same data three times, but bridge tables are rarely massive enough to worry about their space requirements. Typically performance concerns are more important, and this would be the most performant structure. More so than an IOT.
So to summarize: if you will never have more than one index, every query will use that index every time, you usually are after most or all of the columns in the table, and you don't care about compression, then use an IOT. Otherwise, stick with normal heap tables for most other situations. Because bridge tables almost by definition require two indexes and two possible access directions, they are not the best candidates for IOTs.

So if I wanted to just do this
select from CrossWalk where OtherTable_ID=2 and OtherTableName = User This is just an example.
Would an IOT not be the best idea? Perhaps just index those 2 columns?

It is very probable that this Crosswalk table could be millions of rows at some point. Thats why I want to index it carefully

@coloradoman, Please read my post carefully, there's a lot of conceptual content there that may take a bit to digest. I do think an IOT is not the best structure for a bridge table like this, and I hope my rather lengthy explanation above explains why. I also edited it and added a summary paragraph.

I also am leaning towards a composite index and not IOT. From my understanding the way it stores its value in a B tree is with the entire primary key (which in my table is the entire row).
It sounds to me like accessing the table with only parts of the primary key would be inefficent for IOT because it is expecting someone to access the table using the entire primary key.

@coloradoman, not really, no. Whether you access it with one column or two doesn't change how Oracle searches a normal index vs. an IOT index. In your situation, only #2 above in my answer really is determinative. You might have to access the table using MyTable_ID, and an FK constraint protecting that column is probably going to drive you to index it anyway. Once you have two indexes, an IOT falls from grace very quickly.

I also can't take out the OtherTableName column because it is referencing a jsonified table object coming in a REST request. We are trying to link 2 different schemas together using this crosswalk table. One schema has json requests for data changes coming in json REST service, and we are taking that to figure out which rows and tables we need to update in our own database.

@coloradoman, a bridge table should normally have only 2 columns - a key to each of the two tables it is relating in a many-to-many relationship. Anything else is denormalized, and we try to avoid denormalization. Only you know your data model, however; I'm just pointing out that that is a yellow flag requiring a least a second look.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
